# how to move a (large) project to requireJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript, requirejs, systemjs

I have a fairly large Angular 1 / Typescript application (400+ files).
The project is created in Visual Studio, and until know I have manually added and maintained the dependency order of the files in the index.html file.
As the project grows, this becomes more and more cumbersome, and I often find myself adding classes in existing files, simply to avoid having to add another file and add it in index.html/

I’m thinking of moving to requireJs or systemJs, but it is not clear to me what the effort would be.
The app is structured as

```
Root folder
    App.ts
    Index.html
    Module1
        Additional folders
    Module2
        Additional folder
    Etc…
```

All files are using namespace and export of classes. I do not have any references defined in any of the ts files as the dependency order is manually maintained in the index.html, and VS is aware of all included ts definitions.

Would I have to add an import statement to each file for each dependent file / module, or should I create a dependency.ts file in each modules root folder (e.g. Module1) which contains all imports and then import only that one file in all files in the module folder?.

Any help or examples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your case I think you should start by creating a module facade and then work your way toward a single import per module.  The reason being is you'll have a lot of mod1.sub1.Class1 type references that will be a pain to re-write.  Get the facade working then start eliminate the namespace chains.

Comment: if the increasing number of imports is your main concern you can just try outputing the entire compiled application into a single file using the **outFile** compiler configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I'm trying a simple test now with requrieJs, trying to figure out how to create the module façade (exposing multiple classes in a single exported module file).
For the single output file - yes, I did rearrange some of the code into 2 sub (VS) projects, each outputting a single file. Of course I have the options of doing the same for the remaining files, but I think using a module loader is a better approach when the app grows.

Comment: @JesperKristiansen I agree that it is. :) The bundling can be a temporary measure until you get everything moved over.